# How to find the sum of the elements strictly above the secondary diagonal of the matrix using vector<vector<int>>?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, stl, sum

if the input is :

```
4 
1 6 3 1
6 1 3 1
1 3 1 6
3 1 6 1
```

my output should be :

```
18
```

1 + 6 + 3 + 6 + 1 + 1 = 18

the second diagonal is the one that starts at the top right and ands down left

```
       1
     3
   3
 3
```

I need to find the sum of the elements that are strictly above the second diagonal.

This is my code so far:

```
int n , sum = 0;
cin >> n;

vector<vector<int>> A(n);

for (auto rows : A)
   for (auto elements : rows)
       cin >> elements;

for(auto x : A) 
   sum += A[x] [n - x];

cout << sum;
```

I m new to vector on a matrix. Also if you guys know where I could improve my vector skills, and better understand stl vector, your advice would be very helpful!

If you could help me it would be very appreciated!

Thank you all for answering!

Comment: *I m new to vector on a matrix* -- You retrieve or set the elements using exactly the same syntax as you would if it were a regular 2D array using `[][]`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie if you could help me with the code it would be very helpful!

Comment: The second diagonal of the input is (1,3,3,3) not (1,3,3,1)

Comment: A `std::vector<vector<int>>` requires you to not only set up the number of rows, but also you need to size the inner vector. Your code only does the first thing, but not the second.

Comment: @BlueTune i changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the vector shall be defined like

```
vector<vector<int>> A(n, std::vector<int>( n ) );
```

These loops shall use references to objects

```
for (auto &rows : A)
   for (auto &elements : rows)
       cin >> elements;
```

To find the sum you can use an index variable as for example

```
long long int sum = 0;

for ( auto n = A.size(); n-- != 0;  )
{
    for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        sum += A[A.size() - n - 1][i];
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main() 
{
    size_t n = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter the size of a matrix: ";

    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v( n, std::vector<int>( n ) );

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( auto &row : v )
    {
        for ( auto &item : row ) item = std::rand() % n;
    }

    for ( const auto &row : v )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : row ) std::cout << item << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    long long int sum = 0;

    for ( auto n = v.size(); n-- != 0; )
    {
        for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            sum += v[v.size() - n - 1][i];
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\nThe sum is equal to " << sum << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter the size of a matrix: 5
4 4 0 2 0 
1 4 4 3 3 
3 3 1 0 4 
2 0 2 3 2 
2 1 3 0 3 

The sum is equal to 27
```

Comment: it works, but could you explain me this part  ````for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < n; i++ )```` ,  why a vector in a for-loop and the size_type. Thanks

Comment: @MogovanJonathan: `std::vector<int>::size_type` is mainly just `std::size_t`

Comment: @MogovanJonathan For the size of a vector the class template std::vector introduces an alias for unsigned integer type named like size_type. This is an ordinary for loop. See my updated answer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i accepted your answer. Thank you! Also, where did you learn vector<vector<int>> ?

Answer (score 0):

Use indexes:

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < A[i].size() - i; j++)
       sum += A[i][j];
...
```

Comment: And how does this answer the question?

Comment: @ArminMontigny read the question first, and then you will understand how it answers the question